# Ler um JSON por http em AngularJS não funciona

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Olá
Estou tentando ler um JSON via http usando AngularJS (preciso usar obrigatoriamente o AngularJS) e não consigo nem exibir os primeiros dados do JSON pois ele não tem uma string que eu possa chamar no function(response) em $scope.countries = response. ? não sei como chamar os dados se eles nao tem uma string.

Não consigo alterar os dados do JSON pois eles vem de uma base que nao tenho como editar e nao posso ler incorporando os dados direto no js, tem mesmo que vir do http.

Meu js e html:

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

app.controller('ArqCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("https://endereco.json").success(function(response) {
        $scope.countries = response.''  ;
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test for archive</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div ng-controller="ArqCtrl">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="country in countries">

                {{ country.name + ',' + country.capital + ',' + country.bd + ',' + country.pop }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
    
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

O JSON que esta no endereco tem os dados:

```
[{"name":"United States","capital":"Washington, D.C.","pop":321645000,"latlng":[38.0,-97.0],"bd":["CAN","MEX"]}]
```

Se alguem puder ajudar, obrigado

Comment: o que vem no response.data ?

Comment: Nada @LevyhNunes, ja coloquei response.data mas não retorna nada. :(

Comment: Você pode estar tendo erros de cors

Comment: verifica tbm se mostra algum erro no console

Comment: Primeiro, não se acessa um json direto da raiz https://, deve ter algum domínio ou site antes, tente acessar o endereço manualmente e ver o que está vindo algo: `https://endereco.json`, eu costumo utilizar  `ServiceNome.RequestData(params).then(function(result) { ... });` para trazer os dados. Você pode usar o [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) para testar a requisição.

Comment: teste usar: `JSON.parse(result)`

Comment: Olha, eu [fiz aqui um exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/ubcjdLf2/) só pra ilustrar isso.